# More Null Free Shellcode

Tags: shell, assembly, shellcode

I need to find null-free replacements for the following instructions so I can put the following code in shellcode.

The first instruction I need to convert to null-free is:

```
mov ebx, str    ; the string containing /dev/zero
```

The string str is defined in my .data section.
The second is:

```
mov    eax,0x5a
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds, er, dubious - what's this for?

Comment: The mov ebx, str is for opening /dev/zero so I can initialize memory to 0s.

Comment: The mov eax, 0x90 is setting an opcode for a linux system call

Comment: I think the question is more like "what do you intend to do?".  People asking for shellcode advice tend to be up to no good.  And a lot of people don't want any part of that.

Comment: Oh, I'm not doing anything malicious, just kind of fooling around.  I'm a computer science student at school, and eventually want to look into a field in security.  I wrote a program that doesn't contain shellcode, but writes shellcode to its memory and executes it.  Now I want to turn the whole program into shellcode.  I guess just an esoteric experiment.

Comment: Also I figured out the mov eax, 0x5a using xor, inc, and shl.  I am still stuck on the first one though.

Comment: The first one is, with the constraints that you gave (the string being in the `.data` section), not really possible in the type of code you're attempting to create - self-contained and fully position-independent. These mean you can't know anything about specific data / code locations. To solve this, get creative ... don't insist on the string being in `.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what you want to learn is how assembly code is made up, what type of instruction choices ends up in assembly code with specific properties, then (on x86/x64) do the following:

1. Pick up Intel's instruction set reference manuals (four volumes as of this writing, I think). They contain opcode tables (instruction binary formats), and detailed lists of all allowed opcodes for a specific assembly mnemonic (instruction name).
   Familiarize yourself with those and mentally divide them into two groups - those that match your expected properties (like, not containing the 'x' character ... or any other specific one), and those that don't.  The 2nd category you need to eliminate from your code if they're present.
2. Compile your code telling the compiler *not to discard* compile intermediates:

   ```
   gcc -save-temps -c csource.c
   ```
3. Disassemble the object file:

   ```
   objdump -d csource.o
   ```
4. The disassembly output from `objdump` will contain the *binary instructions* (opcodes) as well as the instruction names (mnemonics), i.e. you'll see exactly which opcode format was chosen. You can now check whether any opcodes in there are from the 2nd set as per 1. above.
5. The *creative* bit of the work comes in now. When you've found an instruction in the disassembly output that *doesn't* match the expectations/requirements you have, look up / create a substitute (or, more often, a substitute sequence of several instructions) that gives the same end result but is only made up from instructions that *do* match what you need.
   Go back to the compile intermediates from above, find the `csource.s` assembly, make changes, reassemble/relink, test.
6. If you want to make your assembly code standalone (i.e. not using system runtime libraries / making system calls directly), consult documentation on your operating system internals (how to make syscalls), and/or disassemble the runtime libraries that ordinarily do so on your behalf, to learn how it's done.

Since 5. is definitely homework, of the same sort like *create a C `for()` loop equivalent to a given `while()` loop*, don't expect too much help there. The instruction set reference manuals and experiments with the (dis)assembler are what you need here.

Additionally, if you're studying, attend lessons on how compilers work / how to write compilers - they do cover how assembly instruction selection is done by compilers, and I can well imagine it to be an interesting / challenging term project to e.g. write a compiler whose output is guaranteed to contain the character '`?`' (`0x3f`) but never '`!`' (`0x21`). You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the constant load via `xor` to clear plus `inc` and `shl` to get any set of bits you want.

The least fragile way I can think of to load an unknown constant (your unknown `str`) is to load the constant `xor` with some value like `0xAAAAAAAA` and then `xor` that back out in a subsequent instruction.  For example to load `0x1234`:

```
   0:   89 1d 9e b8 aa aa       mov    %ebx,0xaaaab89e
   6:   31 1d aa aa aa aa       xor    %ebx,0xaaaaaaaa
```

You could even choose the `0xAAAAAAAA` to be some interesting ascii!